# Why does "Inside the Java Virtual Machine" say "NewbornBaby need not be loaded"?

Tags: java, jvm, classloader

[Inside the Java Virtual Machine - Chapter 7 The Lifetime of a Type - Initialization](https://www.artima.com/insidejvm/ed2/lifetype4.html) has code snippet like below.

```
class NewParent {

    static int hoursOfSleep = (int) (Math.random() * 3.0);

    static {
        System.out.println("NewParent was initialized.");
    }
}

class NewbornBaby extends NewParent {

    static int hoursOfCrying = 6 + (int) (Math.random() * 2.0);

    static {
        System.out.println("NewbornBaby was initialized.");
    }
}

class Example2 {

    // Invoking main() is an active use of Example2
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Using hoursOfSleep is an active use of NewParent,
        // but a passive use of NewbornBaby
        int hours = NewbornBaby.hoursOfSleep;
        System.out.println(hours);
    }

    static {
        System.out.println("Example2 was initialized.");
    }
}
```

And then it says *In the above example, executing main() of Example2 causes only Example2 and NewParent to be initialized. NewbornBaby is not initialized and need not be loaded*.

`Example2` references `NewbornBaby`, I think it should be "JVM loads `NewbornBaby` at first and it finds that `NewbornBaby` doesn't have `hoursOfSleep` field, then it proceeds to load `NewbornBaby`'s superclass `NewParent`". So, why does *Inside the Java Virtual Machine* say *NewbornBaby need not be loaded*?

After `javac Example2.java`, I run `java -verbose:class Example2`, below is part of the output.

```
[Loaded Example2 from file:/Users/jason/trivial/]
[Loaded sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper from /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_181.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar]
[Loaded java.lang.Class$MethodArray from /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_181.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar]
[Loaded java.lang.Void from /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_181.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar]
Example2 was initialized.
[Loaded NewParent from file:/Users/jason/trivial/]
[Loaded NewbornBaby from file:/Users/jason/trivial/]
[Loaded java.lang.Math$RandomNumberGeneratorHolder from /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_181.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar]
[Loaded java.util.Random from /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_181.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar]
NewParent was initialized.
1
```

It demonstrates that the JVM does indeed load `NewbornBaby`.

Comment: Please check the answer by [Sotirios Delimanolis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22777135/4296884). It might help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You ran into a common confusion of class *loading* and *initialization*.

The article you've linked, describes *initialization*, which is triggered by some [well defined actions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.1):

> #### §12.4.1. When Initialization Occurs
>
> A class or interface type T will be initialized immediately before the first occurrence of any one of the following:
>
> - `T` is a class and an instance of `T` is created.
> - A `static` method declared by `T` is invoked.
> - A `static` field declared by `T` is assigned.
> - A `static` field declared by `T` is used and the field is not a constant variable ([§4.12.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4)).

Your code is accessing a `static` field in class `NewParent` which will trigger the initialization of that class. The way you access it, is irrelevant. So when you run your code without logging, it printed

```
Example2 was initialized.
NewParent was initialized.
1
```

So `NewbornBaby` has not been initialized, as none of the specified trigger actions were performed.

Class *loading*, however, is an entirely different thing. Its timing is intentionally unspecified, except that it must happen before initialization. A JVM may eagerly load all referenced classes, even before the application starts, or defer the loading, until either, the verifier or the application needs it.

---

At this point, it's important to understand that while the compiler will check whether the referenced `static` field exists and will find it in the class `NewParent`, it will produce bytecode still using the type that has been used in the source code. So, loading the specified class `NewbornBaby` at runtime is unavoidable (the article is wrong in this regard), even if it won't get initialized (which the article seems to confuse with loading).

Compare with [JLS, §13.1. The Form of a Binary](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-13.html#jls-13.1-110-D):

> Given a legal expression denoting a field access in a class `C`, referencing a field named `f` that is not a constant variable and is declared in a (possibly distinct) class or interface `D`, we define the qualifying type of the field reference as follows:
>
> ...
>
> - If the reference is of the form *TypeName*`.f`, where *TypeName* denotes a class or interface, then the class or interface denoted by *TypeName* is the qualifying type of the reference.
>
> ...
>
> The reference to `f` must be compiled into a symbolic reference to the erasure ([§4.6](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.6)) of the qualifying type of the reference, plus the simple name of the field, `f`.

In other words, the expression `NewbornBaby.hoursOfSleep` will get compiled using `NewbornBaby` as the qualifying type and the runtime has to find the actual field again in the supertype, like the compiler did. If there was a different version of `NewbornBaby` at runtime having a matching field of that name and type, that field was used instead.

There is no way around loading the class `NewbornBaby` at runtime, to find out which scenario applies.

---

Further, it's off-specification when the class loading will be logged. It seems, it does not happen when the loading is triggered, but when the loading completed. This does already include some verification steps, including loading and checking whether the superclass exists and is compatible (i.e. not an `interface`, not `final`, etc.).

So when the verifier encounters an access to class `NewbornBaby`, it triggers the loading of that class, which triggers the loading of `NewParent`. But the loading of `NewParent` completes first and is reported first, as its completion is necessary to complete the loading of `NewbornBaby` which is logged afterwards.

But, as said, that's implementation specific. Only the initialization is precisely specified.

Comment: Sorry, the output of `java -verbose:class Example2` might be misleading and I have edited my question. [Inside the Java Virtual Machine - Chapter 7 The Lifetime of a Type - Initialization](https://www.artima.com/insidejvm/ed2/lifetype4.html) says *executing main() of Example2 causes only Example2 and NewParent to be initialized. NewbornBaby is not initialized and need not be loaded*. My question is why NewbornBaby need not be loaded. Without loading NewbornBaby at first, how does JVM know NewbornBaby's superclass is NewParent and it should proceed to load NewParent?

Comment: Your concerns are valid. You could have kept your log in the question, as it demonstrates that the JVM does indeed load the class. Your first version read as if your question was about the order of the loading. I updated the answer to address that the class indeed needs to be loaded.

Answer (score 1):

In this case as you quote in the book JVM loads `NewbornBaby` at first and it finds that `NewbornBaby` doesn't have `hoursOfSleep` field, then it proceeds to load `NewbornBaby`'s superclass `NewParent`": the JVM try to load the `NewbornBaby` but this class is a subclass of `NewParent` so to be load it needs to load all the class methods of its superclass, so to load the `newbornBaby`(first) is necessary to load `NewParent`(second) as part of loading `newbornBaby`.

In resume the load of `NewParent`, looks like it loads first, and it does but remember that this is a subprocess of loading the `newbornBaby`(process that already started)