# Preloading class will not report an error until this class is first actively used even though the class file is missing or has errors?

Tags: java, jvm

I was reading the article below and had a question about the following passage:

> The jvm specification allows a class loader to preload a class when it expects it to be used,If encountered during preloading.class file is missing or has errors,The class loader must report a linkerror when the program first actively uses the class. If this class has not been actively used by the program,Then the class loader will not report an error.

Given the following code:

```
public class MyTest1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println(MyChild1.str); 
    }
}

class MyParent1 {
    public static  String str = "hello world";
    static {
        System.out.println("MyParent1 static block");
    }
}
class MyChild1 extends MyParent1 {
    public static String str2 = "welcome";
    static {
        System.out.println("MyChild1 static block");
    }
}
```

The operation result is:

```
MyParent1 static block
hello world
```

MyChild1 is not used actively but is loaded.

```
[Loaded com.yc.test.classloader.MyParent1 from 
file:/C:/Users/nhn/IdeaProjects/demo/out/production/demo/]
[Loaded com.yc.test.classloader.MyChild1 from 
file:/C:/Users/nhn/IdeaProjects/demo/out/production/demo/]
```

But when I run the code above after removing the class file of MyChild1, NoClassDefFoundError occurred.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/yc/test/classloader/MyChild1
    at com.yc.test.classloader.MyTest1.main(MyTest1.java:5)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.yc.test.classloader.MyChild1
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    ... 1 more
```

The operation result contradicts with the passage. Why?

https://www.tutorialfor.com/blog-228663.htm

Comment: Is this a question, or are you stating a fact?

Comment: You haven’t asked a question yet, but it seems, your question is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63756025/2711488) even if it is not visible at the first glance but becomes apparent after careful reading. The “preload” of your cite seems to be about speculative loading which does not happen here at all. Generally, I’d prefer different documentation about such topic than an article that doesn’t name an author and fails at basic things like formatting and grammar already. Even its first sentence “The loading of a class refers to the class.” is incomprehensible.

Comment: @BeUndead It's a question. The operation result after I remove the class file of MyChild1 contracicts with the passage above. NoClassDefFoundError is reported, but the passage says that "If this class has not been actively used by the program,then the class loader will NOT report an error."

Comment: @Holger Sorry, let me ask this question in another way. Why NoClassDefFoundError occurred? In which process of class loading is NoClassDefFoundError reported? I only have a limited understanding of the JVM and I just know the whole process of class loading is loading, linking(verification, preparation, resolution), and initializing.

Comment: Just don't blindly trust random articles from the internet. E.g it says "jvm specification allows a class loader to preload", but there is no even a single occurence of the word "preload" in the specification.

Comment: @Anson follow the link of my previous comment and read carefully. It’s about the same constellation. `MyChild1.str` *is* an active use of `MyChild1` that requires *loading* of `MyChild1`. Only after it has been loaded, the JVM can determine that it doesn’t declare `str` but has a superclass that declares an appropriate field. Since your program ends up accessing a field in `MyParent1` but no member of `MyChild1`, the class `MyChild1` is not *initialized*. As the linked answer explains, you must not confuse class loading and initialization.

Comment: @apangin so it doesn’t forbid it. In my opinion, the bigger problem is the subsequent sentence that is claiming the existence of a restriction that doesn’t exist in this form. While “first actively uses” is as fuzzy as “preload”, it’s still bearing enough meaning to conclude that the statement clearly contradicts the JLS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This cited article is wrong, even with these undefined terms like “preload” and “when the program first actively uses the class”.

If “preload” is supposed to mean eagerly resolving referenced classes, we can refer to the Java Language Specification, [§12.1.2.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.1.2):

> An implementation may resolve symbolic references from a class or interface that is being linked very early, even to the point of resolving all symbolic references from the classes and interfaces that are further referenced, recursively. (This resolution may result in errors from these further loading and linking steps.)

It then states about the potential errors:

> The only requirement on when resolution is performed is that any errors detected during resolution must be thrown at a point in the program where some action is taken by the program that might, directly or indirectly, require linkage to the class or interface involved in the error. Using the "static" example implementation choice described above, **loading and linkage errors could occur before the program is executed** if they involved a class or interface mentioned in the class Test or any of the further, recursively referenced, classes and interfaces.

So it’s definitely wrong to say that loading or linkage errors were only reportable “when the program first actively uses the class”, even when the article didn’t care to explain what constitutes an active use.

As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63763771/2711488), *initialization* is performed under well defined conditions and the behavior of your program is understandable when overcoming the common confusion of *loading* and *initialization*. To evaluate the expression `MyChild1.str`, loading of the class `MyChild1` is unavoidable and only after the class has been loaded, it is possible to determine that it doesn’t have a field `str` but a superclass that has. So while it will be unavoidably *loaded* it will not get *initialized*, as neither of the specified actions (like the access to a `static` field) has been performed.

As you can recognize from your stack trace, the `NoClassDefFoundError` has been thrown right before evaluating the expression `MyChild1.str`, which is already as lazy as possible. Valid places to throw the error would have been the beginning of the method’s execution, the loading and resolving of the `Mytest1` class, or, as the linked part of the specification says, even before the execution of the entire program starts.

While the point of loading and resolving and hence, the point of throwing the error, is left to the particular implementation, all valid implementations will agree in throwing the error before coming to evaluate the expression `MyChild1.str`.